# Stopping user entering numerical value in a texbox when using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to stop the user to enter a numerical value in the search criteria text box when the Dropdown value is MBID  The code works I only need help on how to resolve the validation issue

[image]

C# Code

```
protected bool searchData()
{
      string val = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
 switch (val)
  {
      case "MBID":

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
         {
             con.Open();
               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  count(*)

                        from Patient  where MBID = @SearchCriteria ", con))
                {

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        int userCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        da.Fill(dt);
           }
       }

    }

  }
```

The Search button call the code below

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormValidation()) if (searchData())
         {

            BindGrid();
            inputUpdateFornData();

        }

    }
```

HTML Code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <asp:ListItem Value="MBID">MBID</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="HPNumber">HP Number</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="NHSNumber">NHS Number</asp:ListItem>
```

I cannot used the code below because numerical value can be entered for the  other option of the dropdown

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchCriteria" runat="server />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server"     ControlToValidate="txtSearchCriteria" Type="Integer"
  Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Value must be an integer!" />
```

Comment: you can validate from code behing part as well. or you can try by using javascript validation too. like document.getElementById("DropDownList1").value =="MBID" then you can check for numeric value only

Answer (score 0):

hello please try below code for javascript validation
below is javascript code

```
 <script>
        function validateSearch()
        {
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("<%= ddlSearch.ClientID %>");
            var txtSearch = document.getElementById("<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>");
            if (dropdown.value == "MBID")
            {
                var reg = /^\d+$/;
                if (!reg.test(txtSearch.value)) {
                    alert("Please enter proper value");
                    txtSearch.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

            </script>
```

and below is aspx code of dropdown and textbox.

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSearch">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="MBID" Value="MBID"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Name" Value="Name"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" OnClientClick="return validateSearch();" />
```

Comment: Hello how to call the validateSearch() function in the textbox. Thanks

Comment: You have to call this function on button click event

Comment: You have to add this code on your search button OnClientClick="return validateSearch()"

Comment: What to do if my button already has a Onclick function as show <asp:Button  ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" /> I added the function as you said the validation works but when a numerical value is entered the code does not do anything

Comment: you want validation like when user has selected "MBID" at that time user can only enter numeric value right?

Comment: Yes Please only numerical value can be entered in the textbox when user select "MBID" in the dropdown

Comment: Yes then above code is for same it will fire only if your dropdown value is MBID

Comment: Hi Kevin  I updated my code for you to understand my issue.  The problem is I cannot add another onclick function on the btnSearch. If I do so the validation works but btnSearch_Click does not work anymore. Thanks

Comment: @EricMbiada I have added my javascript function on OnClientClick not onClick event of button so it will not stuck

Comment: Hi Kevin  this the asp button  <asp:Button  ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="return validateSearch()" /> as you can see I added your OnClientClick.  But when I test the code the validation  work when I entered non numerical value in the box but when I entered numerical value the code does not work look like the OnClientClick function is stopping the OnClick to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you please check on browser console does javascript gives any error? because same code working in my machine

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```
        try
        {
            int d = int.Parse(txtSearchCriteria.Text);
            //if works str is a number
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It isn't a number!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ClientValidationFunction="validateFunction"` in your CompareValidator.

And write validation function as follows-

```
function validateFunction(s,args){
   if (yourdropdown.value == "MBID")
   {
        // Your code
   }
}
```

If you want server validation , add `OnServerValidate` attribute and handler function on server side.